# How do I access this json data without a variable to call?

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

How do I access this json data using this jquery script?

The original script worked with a JSON file in which all the data was nested under "markers:" My JSON isn't nested like that. So I am having trouble figuring out how to access it correctly.

Been tinkering with this and researching other examples, but seems like others are working with a JSON file that is more similar to the original docs.

My Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
                // Also works with: var yourStartLatLng = '59.3426606750, 18.0736160278';
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function() { 
  // This URL won't work on your localhost, so you need to change it
  // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
  $.getJSON( 'http://localhost:3000/locations.json', function(data) { 
    $.each( data, function(marker) {
      $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude), 
        'bounds': true,
      }).click(function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': marker.content }, this);
      });
    });
  });
});
        });
</script>
```

My JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "address": "woo woo woo",
    "latitude": 10.6959353,
    "longitude": -61.13116189999999,
    "url": "locations/2.json"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "address": "hi hi hi",
    "latitude": 20.784575,
    "longitude": -73.9488803,
    "url": "/locations/3.json"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "address": "blah blah balh",
    "latitude": 50.70984199999999,
    "longitude": -72.958056,
    "url": "/locations/4.json"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you show an example with a json file that works properly?

Comment: this is the original file that correctly loads its json. http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-json.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you have two problems in your code. First, your function in the `$.each` callback should accept two parameters, the first of which is the index of the current element in the array:

```
$.each( data, function(idx, marker) {
```

Here, `marker` is not an existing property or requirement in your data or data structure, but rather a placeholder name for the object at position `idx` in your array. For example, when `idx=0`, you will find

```
marker === {
  "id": 2,
  "address": "woo woo woo",
  "latitude": 10.6959353,
  "longitude": -61.13116189999999,
  "url": "locations/2.json"
}
```

This points to the second problem, which is that the objects in your JSON file don't have a `content` property, so in the click function `marker.content` will be undefined.

If that's not enough to get you going, then please provide some more information about the behaviour that you're expecting to see, what's happening instead, any messages that might be appearing in your javascript console, etc.

**UPDATE:** In response to the comment thread, in addition to the originally missing code, the complete solution also includes not violating the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The JSON file being loaded must be loaded by the browser from the same location as the page containing the script.

Comment: Okay. I edited it to... `code $.each( data, function(i, marker) {` the problem is that pins are not appearing on my map based on the JSON data. I'm not getting any errors in the javascript console.

Comment: I will add a content field to the json file.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your function is being properly called, and iterating over the objects in your JSON file as you expect? For instance, with `console.log(marker.address)` after `$.each(...`, before `$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker'...`

Comment: How do I see if it is iterating through my JSON?

Comment: The easiest way is to use the JavaScript console, perhaps by logging a property of the `marker` object, as in my last comment.

Comment: Sorry about that @Michael. I included console.log(marker.address) as well as tried marker.latitude and returned nothing.

Comment: No problem. That is interesting, because it means that either the init function you are binding to the gmap is not being called, or the `$.getJSON` function is not retrieving any data. You can see at this jsfiddle that the JSON and `$.each` function appear to work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/munderwood/Y9U5A/. It may be worth posting more of your HTML and javascript.

Comment: Alternatively, another debugging approach at this point is to see whether the init or getJSON functions are working at all. Try putting a `console.log('in init');` before the `$.getJSON` line, and `console.log('got json: ' + data);` in between the `$.getJSON` and `$.each` lines.

Comment: alright. I'm looking at the example code files. I can't even get the demo file to load JSON with the json on my localhost (and formatted exactly as the demo JSON). Is the demo code for the JSON example wrong? Is it just me? [plugin website](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) and [example files](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/downloads/detail?name=jquery-ui-map-3.0-rc.zip&can=2&q=)

Comment: The page you are testing this with is also being served on your computer via port 3000, right? That is, it's something like `http://localhost:3000/testjson.html`? If it's not the same port, even on the same host, then it violates the same-origin policy linked to in your question's original code.

Comment: OK - once I put the example files in a directory with a port address the JSON example worked. Interesting to note that even with the json in the same file directory with a local address like this 'file:///' it wasn't loading the json.

Comment: Glad that finally got sorted out, @sirius. I've updated my answer so that it now contains the correct solution to your question. Please feel free to upvote and accept it, if this helped you solve your problem.